# String throws a Vector Subscript Debug Assertion

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, vector

So I am trying to read times in from a text file and take the header line out of each entry.

The file is formated as

> Board Number # 15
>     Feb 06 10:00
>     Feb 06 11:00
>     Board Number #12...

With a bunch different numbers of entries for each board. To do this I am using the following code

```
int main()
{
    fstream log_file;
     //get the dat file
    std::vector <TFile*> files;
    std::vector <std::string> t, fnames;
    int bn[4], nruns[4];
    fstream runtimes;
    std::string line; 
    runtimes.open("runlogs.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (!runtimes.eof() && runtimes.is_open()) {
        while (getline(runtimes, line)) {
            try {
                std::cout << line << std::endl;
                if (line.find("#") != std::string::npos) {
                    std::istringstream templine(line);
                    std::string temp;
                    while (getline(templine, temp, ' ')) {
                        try {
                            stof(temp);
                            fnames.push_back(temp);
                            i++;
                        }
                        catch (std::exception& e) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    t.push_back(line);
                    //std::cout << line << std::endl;
                    nruns[i - 1]++;
                }
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) {
                            std::cout << "error of form: " << e.what() << std::endl;  
            }
```

My problem is that the program is throwing a debug assertion error, with no output. This is confusing me, as the error it is throwing is a vector subscript out of range assertion.

EDIT:: The debugger gives the following output:

[Screen shot of the debugger at break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJRwW.png)

Following through the debugging, it continues to be before the first output, referencing the same line in the vector include. I also have fixed the potential issue with nruns, but that has not changed it at all. The debugging also throws an exception as

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F4A0B45 (ucrtbased.dll)

Comment: "_Any tips?_" Don't index the `vector`/`string` out of range. Or, alternatively, once you get such assertion failure, you could attach to your program with a debugger, click retry, and investigate the place, and the variables, where such assertion occurs.

Comment: you declare `line` twice

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error moving the doe over to here.  Algirdas, the error seems to occur at the use of line, it is actually being run in a debugger

Comment: `nruns[i - 1]++;` so if there's no '#' in the first line, you'll increment `nruns[-1]` ? That doesn't look very safe.

Comment: @SilasKGrossberndt "_it is actually being run in a debugger_" So what's stopping you from using said debugger, to investigate the investigate the local variables, to see if they match your expectations, and to see which variables - don't? To step through your application, to see how the code execution got to this point?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I just took your advice, and the output makes very little sense, there is no local variable that seems to have any connection to this error, I will add the output as an update

Comment: How many lines there are in your input file ?

Comment: 43 lines in runlog.txt

Comment: `i` is incremented if `stof` doesn't throw exception, so if you have more 5 lines with format `Board Number # 15` where number can be parsed, and you try to write `nruns[i - 1]` but `nruns` has only 4 items, you access element out of range.

Comment: there are only 4 (I wrote the text file myself)

Comment: @SilasKGrossberndt "_I just took your advice, and the output makes very little sense_" Where did I advise you to look through the output? I advised you to **step through** your code, line-by-line, with a debugger, while looking through values of local variables - the process which everyone uses, to debug their programs.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius My apologies, that was what I meant. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `runtimes.is_open()`. When it was removed, and replaced simply with !eof() it ran with out this issue. The file name was actually wrong, but now it is having a similar issue at the end of the file.

EDIT: In fixing the file name, and going back and rechecking some values, one of the files called by a line of runtimes was corrupted. Added try/catch blocks, and fixed behavior at the end of the file, and it works fine now. Thanks for the help, sorry to bother you with something so trivial, still learning the approaches.